# Where can I find a list of all available Python identifiers known to the interpreter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, interpreter, cpython

I searched in the [CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython) source code, but I didn't find a list of all available identifiers. I'm talking about identifiers, which the interpreter knows, not about builtins, that can be listed like this:

```
import builtins
dir(builtins)
```

Note, that identifiers like `__new__`, `__init__` and `cls` are not listed, but the interpreter knows them.

Comment: What's special about `cls`?

Comment: If you're asking "where can I find a list of attribute and method names that are invoked by the language under special circumstances?", check out https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html. Anything starting with "__" on that page is a good bet.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers